# How to reconfigure custom post type after it has been defined?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using a WordPress theme that adds a custom post type.

This is somewhat useful, but would be even more useful if I could adjust some of the CTP's configuration.

In particular, I need to adjust the capabilities defined on the CTP. I already have an array of the capability values needed, e.g.,

```
$caps = array(
  'publish_posts'       => 'activate_plugins',
  'read_post'           => 'read',
  ... etc
);
```

Is there a generic way to reconfigure a CTP with these values after it has been defined, i.e, via functions.php?

Or would I need to overwrite whatever theme code is creating the CTP, perhaps using a child theme?

Comment: You may have more help for that on the site for WordPress development questions : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can reconfigure the already defined CPT's properties. By using following filter: `register_post_type_args`

Src: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_post_type_args/

> Filters the arguments for registering a post type.

For example you can change slug like this:

```
add_filter('register_post_type_args', 'movies_to_films', 10, 2);
function movies_to_films($args, $post_type){

    if ($post_type == 'movies'){
        $args['rewrite']['slug'] = 'films';
    }

    return $args;
   }
```

You can edit capabilities similarly see already answered question which solved exact problem:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/215697/30852

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks @mohsin, exactly what i was searching for. Works perfectly!

Comment: @AndyHarvey great to know! Happy coding with WordPress!